# Mysql: Partitioning wihout Primary Key

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have the following table with HUGE amount of data, this is why I want to split or partition it. The problem is I want to partition by a column that is no primary key: project_id. In my case there will be MAXIMUM 2 or 3 different project ids...

```
- id (PRIMARY KEY, AUTO INCREMENT)
- project_id (INT)
- username (UNIQUE)
- username_md5 (UNIQUE)
(- ... more but irrelevant columns)
```

As you can see I have 3 columns that I need to guarantee to be UNIQUE (id, username, username_md5).
Now, I would like to do a RANGE partitioning on the project_id column.
The only solution that I came up with is making an ugly 4-Column PRIMARY KEY for all those columns (Partitioning requires that all columns in the partitioning expression must be part of every unique key).

Now, I'm wondering

A) is a 4-column primary key just fine and usable?

B) is there a better solution for my partitioning?

C) otherwise I would do it manually by creating a "dynamic" table for each project_id that I have, might this be the easiest solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove your **primary** / unique key , and make it a simple key, and than do a simple range partition on the project_id, now it does need to be key at all

You will still have fast access, since those fields are indexed.

You may still want to preserve uniqueness :

- do it in application layer
- do it using nested inserts with selects
- you may use additional table with unique constraints added their (only the combination), hold s reference to the combination in your table

Comment: Hello Michael, I don't understand your solution.
So, I should drop my primary key and create a unique key instead?
should the unique key span across all 4 columns as well?
otherwise, project_id cannot be unique, so what kind of key should i use for it?
Thanks for replying.

Comment: @Benedikt, drop all your primary and unique keys, and make them key only, read the difference between `unique key` and a `key` you do not to add any new span key, i do not think you need to force project_id to be unique by using unique key, why should you, what queries do you execute?

Comment: this works fine, thank you! All 4 columns have now their own simple key.
But how can I guarantee now that "username" and "username_md5" will be unique? (id is autoincrement so I guess it will be fine).

Comment: understood, great solution!